# Get all users and resources from cloud AD

Tags: active-directory, exchangewebservices, office365

We are using Office 365 in our company. How can I get a list of all users and resources with their details in our subscription?

Before, when we had Exchange and Active Directory installed in-house, I was getting all this data directly from our AD, now, when all users are in the cloud how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oleg,

For starters, there is no way to browse the GAL using EWS or EWS Managed API but you can search the GAL. The current methods that have access to the GAL with Exchange 2013 or Office 365 are `ResolveNames`, `ExpandDL`, `FindPeople`, and `GetUserPhoto`. The best option is to use the `FindPeople` operation in EWS (There is no method in EWS Managed API for this operation at this time) because it will allow you to do an `IndexedPageItemView` to view a block at a time.

Here is where it gets interesting. `FindPeople` has an element called **DistinguishedFolderId** that allows you to specify where to look. You can set the value to *directory* to search the GAL, but this only works for on-premises versions of Exchange. If you want to search the GAL on Office 365 you need to specify the **AddressListId** for the GAL, however there are no operations in EWS to get this Id. If you have the proper permissions you can use the PowerShell cmdlet `Get-AddressList`.

Here is a little more information about getting to the GUID:
[Office365’s Global Address List Guid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/bc3e26ec-3cfa-48b6-ba49-9ba59fdd3fa7/office365s-global-address-list-guid?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment)

Once you have the GUID you can set the **ParentFolderId** in `FindPeople` and you will be able to search the GAL.

I hope this information helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark the post as answered.

--- Bob ---